# What are table names where "Checkbox Survey" stores Survey titles, responses etc. in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, survey

I have to integrate `Checkbox Survey` in my application and whenever a user submits the survey I need get that record programmatically using CLR triggers.

But the problem is that I am not able to find the name of of tables which are being used by Checkbox survey to store Survey details, responses etc as there are 170 tables in database.

When I went through the list of all tables did not see any table name which looking like containing all above mentioned record. I also queried many tables but did not get that data.

Please help me if you know the solution of my problem?

Comment: look for sql search software, then you can try to find column names that you use in the application and find matching stored procs and tables. Redgate has a nice on that is free.

Comment: @KevinCook Thanks, I have got the name of tables which I needed with the help of Redgate tool. This tool is very impressive I must say. :)

Comment: @JitenderKumar what are those table? can you please specify?